# ip neigh display a mac address at a coffee store

Tags: networking, ip, routing, arp

I am working at a coffee store and tried command `ip`

```
user@host:~$ ip neigh
192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 lladdr 5c:dd:70:96:80:52 REACHABLE
```

I am aware that `192.168.1.1` is the router address,

How about `5c:dd:70:96:80:52`? is it a mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this command basically outputs the table your PC uses to match IP addresses to physical addresses (MAC address) accessible from your node on the network (i.e. your immediate LAN network only, including any switches/hubs, but not beyond any routers).

If you know that `*.1.1` address is your router, then `5c:dd:70:96:80:52` is its MAC address, at least on its local interface. It will have a different MAC address on its external interface (the one that your ISP sees).